How to implement a repository in quarkus-reactive
I am trying to use quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache for a reactive API that connects to an MSSQL. In Spring Boot, i am doing it like this:
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public interface CommentRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Comment, Long> {
    Flux<Comment> findByPostId(Long postId);
}

When i try to implement PanacheRepository like this:
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CommentRepository implements PanacheRepository<Comment> {

    public Multi<Comment> findByPostId(Long postId) {
        return find("postId", postId).stream();
    }

}


The stream method cannot be resolved. I tried to implement ReactivePanacheRepository but it does not exist in quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache.
What's the correct way to have a repository like this in quarkus-reactive?

Hibernate reactive doesn't support streaming, afaik. Normally, you would use a scrollableResultset and return that as a multi, but that isn't supported. If you perse want a Multi, then you can convert a Uni into a Multi, but this isn't really streaming from the db. It is just returning the items from the list, one by one.
